# How do you optimize searching for all given keywords in a string

Tags: c#, optimization

I have run an SQL query that has text with rich text tags in one of the columns eg.

{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 MS Sans Serif;}{\f1\fnil MS Sans Serif;}}  \viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1033\f0\fs20 Lightbulb task received \par  \par  Action done: called to pt several times, no answers, sms sent to Pt\par  \lang5129\f1\par  }

So for each row in my `DataTable dt` I strip the rich text tags out (with the code below) and that works well

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows )
                        {    
    RichTextBox rtBox = new RichTextBox();
    string rtfText = row["Column1"].ToString();
    rtBox.Rtf = rtfText;
    string plainText = rtBox.Text;
```

Then I have a `public static List<string> keywordList = new List<string>();` With some keywords in it that I want to find if any of those keywords turn up in the plainText string above and then add that word to a HashSet `HashSet<string> myHashSet= new HashSet<string>();` to get all the words that turn up in the text

```
foreach (string word in keywordList)
{
    if (plainText.Contains(word))
    {
        myHashSet.Add(word);
    }
}
```

My problem is this seems to be quite slow when the amount of rows gets higher (around 100) and was wondering how I would optimize this?

Cheers

Comment: Why are you assigning the value to new RichTextBox() in the loop?

Comment: It is for each row in the dataTable I remove the rich text, then find the matching keywords for that row, I then do that all over again for the next row in the dataTable

Comment: Ohhh, right I get you now. Yes you are right, thanks :)

Comment: TLDR; compile a regex like "(word1|word2|word3...)", then you only need to scan the plain text once, locate each match, and add the results to a hashset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way would be to only fetch already filtered records (so having Contains in the SQL).

Otherwise your `foreach` is OK, there is no faster way in C#.*

If you have a performance problem with only 100 rows the problem is likely not with `foreach` and `Contains`.

I think something like the following should be fast enough for humans with 100 rows and few keywords:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows )
{
  var s = row["Column1"].ToString()

  foreach (string word in keywordList)
  {
    if (s.Contains(word))
    {
       myHashSet.Add(word);
       // TODO Delete word from keywordList, but remember that we're inside a foreach
    }
  }
}
```

`*` - @Lolop suggests Regex, but on a match you'll have to scan for what was matched.

Comment: Would doing a regex with a list of the keywords would be more efficient that doing the `foreach` and `contains`? E.G using a Regex string like `(keyword1|keyword2|keyword3)` and doing 1 `IsMatch` check. I don't think it'd make enough of a difference in OP's case, but it could potentially shave some time off.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem might be fact you are creating a RichTextBox for each iteration.
Consider moving the object creation out of loop.

```
   RichTextBox rtBox = new RichTextBox();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows )
    {    
    
    string rtfText = row["Column1"].ToString();
    rtBox.Rtf = rtfText;
    string plainText = rtBox.Text;
```

Comment: Can't say I agree with the last part of your answer. Based on the question you linked the top answer makes it sounds like there is a big difference between `foreach` vs `for`. But as other people in that thread say, the work being done inside the loop is going to offset that different anyway. I only recommend using `for` instead of `foreach` if you have a REALLY performance critical portion of code, or you need the index for something in the loop. In the above case, it might be performance critical, but doing a string `contains` is much more expensive than the loop.

Comment: I've removed it now.

Answer (score 0):

You could find all keywords in text with a LINQ query and then add them parallel in your `HashSet`

```
var usedKeywords = keywordList.Where(x => rtfText.Contains(x));

Parallel.ForEach(usedKeywords, keyword =>
{
    myHashSet.Add(keyword);
});
```